# How to setText color of a single textview in a listview instead of all every textview?

Tags: android, listview

I got a textviews in a custom listview, I know how to set the text color so all the textviews in the list will be changed. But Now, I just want one of the particular view to change color, say there is 10 item in listview, I just want the second textview color to be changed and the rest remain the same. any idea? thanks so much for all the help~

```
public class CheckWinNoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private String[] values;



public CheckWinNoAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, R.layout.list_draw, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chk_tv1);


    textView1.setText(values[position]);




}
```

}

Comment: instead of passing position pass integer value of the listview to which u r trying to set color of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Get View Do it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chk_tv1);


textView1.setText(values[position]);

if(Your Condition Goes Here){
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED); // Did you tried this???
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `ListView` recycles its views in order to avoid *waste* of memory  . So Instead of inflate a new View every time  `getView` is called, assign it to the former parameter `convertView`, and reuse it. The `convertView` is the view you pushed off scrolling for instance. So if the TextView pushed off scrolling is the same of the text view with the different color could happen that you will see "yourcolor" in a text view in which you exepct defaultcolor. So here the need to set everytime getView is called the text color.

```
 @Override 
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (converView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          converView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.chk_tv1);

    int color = (position == YOUR_POSITION) ? yourcolor : defaultcolor;
    textView1.setTextColor(color);

    textView1.setText(values[position]);

}
```

Comment: The ListView recycle the view in order to avoid leak. So Instead of inflate a new View everytime the getView is called, assign it to the former paramter convertView, and reuse it.

Comment: I talked about to add description in your answer, So it helpful for OP's understanding. Anyway +1 from me..

Answer (score 4):

You can change your getView to this one.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chk_tv1);

    if(position== 2){
        textView1.setColor(Color.White);//or whatever you like
    }
    textView1.setText(values[position]);




}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing position pass integer value of the listview to which u r trying to set color of text as:

```
if (position == INT_VALUE)//where INT_VALUE=the position at which u want to setcolor of yours
   textView.setTextColor(color);//which color u want to set 
else
  textView.setTextColor(defaultcolor);//to remaining texts
```